# Преобразование текста в нижний регистр С++

Tags: c++, строки

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой :преобразовать английские символы мне удалось, а вот с русскими не получается.

Я знаю что нужно использовать unsigned char , так как диапазон обычного char от -128 до 127. Но мне не удается решить проблему в практическом виде. Подскажите  мне, как это можно было бы реализовать

```
int main()
{
string str;
cin>>str;

for(int i=0; i<sizeof(str)-1; i++)
{

    if (str[i] > 192 &&  str[i] < 223)
    {
         str = str[i]+32;
    }
}
cout << str << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если компилятор ну никак не хочет работать с русским языком - можно просто забить все русские буквы в верхнем регистре в строку, в такую же забить все в нижнем, и поочередно искать букву в первой строке и брать, если найдена, букву на том же месте в другой строке. Или вообще подготовить 256-байтную таблицу для перевода в нижний регистр - для всех символов, русских и английских...

Comment: Да, я об этом знаю, но не хочется делать это так. Хочу понять как это решить таким способом. А по-поводу таблицы, не знаю, если так не получиться решить, то попробую.

Comment: Никак, toupper/tolower поддерживают только ASCII, можно использовать iconv, или писать таблицу символов самому. Можно ещё поискать стороннюю реализацию на гитхабе, вроде я там чего то похожее видел. Кстати, таблицы символов самому писать не обязательно, можно взять готовые в исходниках iconv :)

Comment: `нужно использовать unsigned char` - нет, `wchar_t` == `2 x unsigned char` на Вин, и 4 на *nix. И проблема в том, что некоторые символы юникода имеют полный размер до 16 unsigned char.

Comment: @NewView, то что поддерживают `toupper`/`tolower` зависит от локали... на nix-системах в русских чисто-8-битных локалях кириллические символы прекрасно поддерживаются...

Comment: @Alex, с кириллицей из стандартного ввода переносимо можно работать только с помощью широких символов... так что либо переходи на них, либо указывай систему/кодировку...

Comment: @NewView, пробую использовать wchar_t , но жалуется error: invalid types ‘wchar_t[int]’ for array subscript, аналогичная ситуация с unsigned char. Как  я понимаю,цикл не правильный, верно?

Comment: `wcin, wstring, wcout.. ` и тд, весь код должен поддерживать wide

Comment: @NewView,верно, так и делал. Я wchar_t пробовал, сделал wstring . И проверил это в байтах ( Вообще не выводит текст) . Проверил в if(str[i]>'А' && str[i]<'Я') str[i]+='я'-'Я';  жалуется на символы.

Comment: Мде.. там же широкий символ. Набейте реальную табличку из 256 русских символов в wchar_t, и сравнивайте с ней. Хотя существует целая вязанка функций для работы с wide символами - mbs* http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wchar.h.html

Comment: Наверное не получается в основном вот из-за этой маленькой (и типично крестовой) ошибочки -- `str = str[i]+32;` (нужно: **`str[i] = str[i]+32;`**). / Кроме того, вы должны переключить консоль в cp-1251 / Если вы в винде, то по умолчанию окошко cmd работает в cp-866 (DOS) / В таком случае диапазон русских upcase будет 128-159 (lowcase также как и в cp1251 на 32 больше)

Comment: Пардон, поправка для [cp-866](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=YGx8Gph3M8u2yM%253A%252CbRI4UFjElAGYhM%252C%252Fm%252F0hb8&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQP-w2jLuadQWnGYtCaJkgEJU19yQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHiYnM2azhAhXQw8QBHUE8BNsQ_B0wCnoECA0QBg&biw=1280&bih=780#imgrc=BML2ZyBS1qIFVM:&vet=1). lowcase больше на 32 для первых 16-ти, для остальных 16-ти на 80.

Comment: @avp, я пишу в терминале ( Linux), как там переключить?

Comment: Сразу в вопросе надо было указать. В Linux терминале сейчас обычно [UTF-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (многобайтная кодировка). Это совсем другая история. Все ASCII символы как обычно 1 байт. Все русские -- 2 байта. Т.о. либо надо все программировать в wide, либо анализировать (в общем-то, самому переводя в UCS) последовательности байт в строке.

Comment: В принципе, большинство эмуляторов терминала в Linux могут переключаться в однобайтную кодировку. Но тогда программу  тоже надо 1) набить в ней, 2) оттранслировать в соответствующей локали 3) запускать тоже в ней (давно такими вещами не занимался...)

Comment: Хотя, если русские буковки в программе не использовать (только их числовые коды), то можно сделать и без этих шагов.

Comment: @avp, я не сильно ещё это понимаю. Можете как-то примерно показать как это должно выглядеть? Я пробовал юзать широкие символы, но как-то мне не удалось. Мне говорили насчет таблицы, но я не особо понял как это делается . Данный момент, я могу сделать проверку на  символы заменяя на определенные, но я считаю что это слишком  глупо.

Comment: Чуть подправил для tolower ASCII символов тоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример "зубочистки на коленке" для однобайтной кодировки [CP-866](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866) (DOS) в Linux.

Для правильного отображения символов надо установить терминал для работы с нужной кодировкой (у меня `xfce4-terminal`)  `[Terminal]->[Set Encoding]->[Cyrillic]->[CP866]`

При этом русские буквы у меня не набираются, поэтому подготовил отдельно в редакторе тестовый файл в стандартной кодировке utf-8

Вот такой -- `q123 ФыВа ёЁ  ЯчсМ йЦуК w234`

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ hexdump -C utf8.txt
00000000  71 31 32 33 20 d0 a4 d1  8b d0 92 d0 b0 20 d1 91  |q123 ........ ..|
00000010  d0 81 20 20 d0 af d1 87  d1 81 d0 9c 20 d0 b9 d0  |..  ........ ...|
00000020  a6 d1 83 d0 9a 20 77 32  33 34 0a                 |..... w234.|
0000002b
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Далее текст из окна терминала, переключенного в CP866.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat t-wincode.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string str;

  cout << "Convert to lowcase cp-866 (DOS) russian symbols in string\n";

  getline(cin, str);

  for(int i=0; i < str.size(); i++) {
      if (isupper((unsigned char)str[i])) // ASCII
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
      else if ((unsigned char)str[i] > 127 &&  (unsigned char)str[i] < 144)
        str[i] = (unsigned char)str[i] + 32;
      else if ((unsigned char)str[i] > 143 &&  (unsigned char)str[i] < 160)
        str[i] = (unsigned char)str[i] + 80;
      else if ((unsigned char)str[i] == 240)
        str[i] = (unsigned char)str[i] + 1;
  }

  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;  
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ t-wincode.cpp
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat utf8.txt
q123 ╨д╤Л╨Т╨░ ╤С╨Б  ╨п╤З╤Б╨Ь ╨╣╨ж╤Г╨Ъ w234
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ iconv -f utf8 -t cp866 utf8.txt
q123 ФыВа ёЁ  ЯчсМ йЦуК w234
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ iconv -f utf8 -t cp866 utf8.txt | ./a.out
Convert to lowcase cp-866 (DOS) russian symbols in string
q123 фыва ёё  ячсм йцук w234
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Как видите, тут по сути ваша программа (*чуть поправленная*).

P.S.
При случае напишу что-то аналогичное для utf-8 ....

---

Ок. Может кому пригодиться (функции преобразования **ucs_to_utf8()** и **utf8_to_ucs()** должны работать и в Си и в С++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;


// returns utf-8 length (max 4) or 0 if error in ucs
// see https://unicode-table.com/en/
int
ucs_to_utf8 (unsigned int ucs, char *utf)
{
  if (ucs < 128) {
    utf[0] = ucs; // ascii
    return 1;
  }
  int l;

  if (ucs < (1 << 11)) { // 0x80 .. 0x7ff  "Latin-1 Supplement" ... cyrillic ... NKo (africa)
    //  110 xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    l = 1;
    utf[0] = (ucs >> 6) | 0xc0;
  } else if (ucs < (1 << 16)) { // 0x800 ... 0xffff Samaritan ... CJK  ... Specials 
    //  1110 xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    l = 2;
    utf[0] = (ucs >> 12) | 0xe0;
    utf[1] = ((ucs >> 6) & 0x3f) | 0x80;
  } else if (ucs > 0xe01ef) // ERROR !!! not defined yet 
    return 0;
  else { // 0x10000 ... 0xe01ef "Linear B Syllabary" ... "CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement" ... 
    // 11110 0xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    l = 3;
    utf[0] = (ucs >> 18) | 0xf0;
    utf[1] = ((ucs >> 12) & 0x3f) | 0x80;
    utf[2] = ((ucs >> 6) & 0x3f) | 0x80;
  }
  utf[l] = (ucs & 0x3f) | 0x80;  // low 6 bits

  return ++l;
}


// return length of symbol (step in input sequence)
// if error, put *ucs = -1 and returns 1
int utf8_to_ucs (const char *str, unsigned int *ucs) {
  if ((unsigned char)*str < 128) { // ascii
    *ucs = *str;
    return 1;
  }

  if ((*str & 0xc0) != 0xc0 || (unsigned char)*str > 0xf7) {
  Err:;
    // at least two high bits should be 11....
    // the number of high ones is the length of utf-8 sequence
    // maximum length of all real unicode is 4 bytes,
    // so max prefix is 1111 0...
    *ucs = -1;
    return 1;
  }

  unsigned int u = 0, i = 1;
  do {
    // six low bits is value, two high must be 10...
    if ((str[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80)
      goto Err;

    u = (u << 6) | (str[i] & 0x3f);
    i++;

  } while (*str & (1 << (7 - i))); // here lookup high zero

  // last utf-8 byte
  // add high ucs bits from str[0]
  unsigned int v = *str & ((1 << (7 - i)) - 1);
  *ucs = u | (v << ((i - 1) * 6)); // all low bits are in `u`

  return i;
}




int main () {
  string str;

  cout << "Conert to lowcase UTF8 russian symbols in string\n";

  getline(cin, str);

  unsigned int l, ucs, cvt;

  for(int i=0; i < str.size(); i += l) {
    if (isupper((unsigned char)str[i])) // ASCII
      str[i] = tolower(str[i]), l = 1;
    else {
      cvt = 0;
      l = utf8_to_ucs(&str[i], &ucs);
      if ((ucs >= 0x410 && ucs < 0x430) || ucs == 0x401) 
    cvt = (ucs == 0x401) ? 0x451 : ucs + 32;
      if (cvt)
    ucs_to_utf8(cvt, &str[i]);
    }
  }

  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для С++ есть библиотека icu. Как раз она может помочь в работе с unicode.

```
int main() {
  while (true) {
    icu::UnicodeString text;
    std::cout << ">>";
    std::cin >> text;
    text.toLower();
    std::cout << "<<";
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    text.toUpper();
    std::cout << "<<";
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Результат работы

```
>>ВЫАаЫВАадывложДВЛожаДЫЛОВАдл
<<выааываадывлождвложадыловадл
<<ВЫААЫВААДЫВЛОЖДВЛОЖАДЫЛОВАДЛ
>>
```

Comment: Напишите, как ее установить и где документация. И второе (м.б. основное), как эта либа ведет себя в случае **неправильного utf-8** во входном потоке?

Comment: У меня ubuntu и она была уже в системе (Вроде так можно ее установить sudo apt install libicu-dev). Если вы используете CMake то просто используйте find_package(ICU REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...) и потом target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  ...)

Comment: http://userguide.icu-project.org/

Comment: Ага, мощная штука с богатой историей. Посмотрел, похоже за пару дней ее не освоить.